# Lightweight sprite animation software

Tags: animation, sprites, spritesheet

Does anyone know of a good lightweight sprite animator solution? I've created a couple of spritesheets using TexturePacker, but I'd like to, for example, create an XML file that tells me frames one through three are part of animation X, and frames 4 through 6 are part of animation Y.

I am primarily a OSX developer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it personally, yet, but I've heard good things about spriter: http://www.brashmonkey.com/spriter.htm